# How to parse a yaml file into ruby hashs and/or arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, hash, yaml

I need to load a yaml file into Hash,
What should I do?

Comment: Please update your selected answer. The one you've selected does not answer your actual question (regardless of whether it's more informative or not)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the YAML module:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html

```
node = YAML::parse( <<EOY )
one: 1
two: 2
EOY

puts node.type_id
# prints: 'map'

p node.value['one']
# prints key and value nodes: 
#   [ #<YAML::YamlNode:0x8220278 @type_id="str", @value="one", @kind="scalar">, 
#     #<YAML::YamlNode:0x821fcd8 @type_id="int", @value="1", @kind="scalar"> ]'

# Mappings can also be accessed for just the value by accessing as a Hash directly
p node['one']
# prints: #<YAML::YamlNode:0x821fcd8 @type_id="int", @value="1", @kind="scalar">
```

http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/parsing_yaml_documents.htm

Comment: This tends to return Syck::Map (or similar objects), not hashes. Any way to have it return (or convert to) a regular ruby Hash?

Answer (score 117):

I would use something like:

```
hash = YAML.load(File.read("file_path"))
```

Comment: Also in Ruby 2.2 symbols are GC'd.

Answer (score 27):

A simpler version of venables' answer:

```
hash = YAML.load_file("file_path")
```

Answer (score 5):

You may run into a problem mentioned at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533352), namely, that the YAML file or stream specifies an object into which the YAML loader will attempt to convert the data into. The problem is that you will need a related Gem that knows about the object in question.

My solution was quite trivial and is provided as an answer to that question. Do this:

```
yamltext = File.read("somefile","r")
yamltext.sub!(/^--- \!.*$/,'---')
hash = YAML.load(yamltext)
```

In essence, you strip the object-classifier text from the yaml-text. Then you parse/load it.