# YAML::load raises undefined class/module error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, psych

I’m implementing paper trail like feature in my rails app. In order to do this, I’m serializing object in YAML. I’ve got `item_at_version` method, which basically does `YAML::load(cached_object)` – this works pretty well, however, I have no idea why, sometimes it returns `undefined class/module _class name_`.
It works with models like Event, Conversation, Note, and many more, but without any reason, it seems to throw that error for models like Dataset, Comment, Student (I’ve tried to find any pattern for that, without any luck).

I’m using rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3p327, psych as YAML Engine (Psych::Version returns 1.3.4).

Ps. When I add require 'model_name' on top of that file, it works like a charm.

Any ideas what should I change/add to get this working?

Edit:
There’s no much code which I can share:

```
def item_at_version
  YAML::load(cached_object)
end
```

But maybe backtrace would be interesting:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:312:in `path2class'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:312:in `resolve_class'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:219:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:238:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:128:in `load'
app/models/history_version.rb:7:in `item_at_version'
app/controllers/history_controller.rb:8:in `show'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `_run__1697733322876708236__process_action__1122943786273335015__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2589517259026276185__call__1369641113040304056__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
bugsnag (1.2.5) lib/bugsnag/rack.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:147:in `handle'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:99:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in start'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `each'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `block in start'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `loop'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `start'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You're likely to get better help if you show some relevant code or a backtrace.

Comment: There’s nothing magic in my code, co I don’t have much to add. I added  full backtrace, maybe this can help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use `YAML.dump` to serialize an object in Ruby, the class name is use as part of the Yaml tag so that the correct class can be used when loading the object. For example:

```ruby
require 'yaml'

class Foo; end

puts YAML.dump Foo.new
```

produces

```yaml
--- !ruby/object:Foo {}
```

When you use `YAML.load` on that string, Psych knows what class to instantiate for the deserialized object.

If you try to call `YAML.load` on a Yaml string that specifies a class that hasn’t been defined, then you will get the error:

```ruby
require 'yaml'

# No Bar class has been defined
YAML.load '--- !ruby/object:Bar {}'
```

produces:

```
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:312:in `path2class': undefined class/module Bar (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:312:in `resolve_class'
...
```

This is because Psych needs to create an instance of class `Bar`, but doesn’t have the definition of the class available. This explains why adding `require 'whatever'` before loading the Yaml works – now Ruby has the definition of the class loaded and so can create an instance of it (note that there is no definitive link between class name and file name in Ruby, it’s just convention).

The solution therefore is to make sure that when you’re loading any Ruby objects from Yaml you have already required any files that may contain definitions of any classes potentially in that Yaml.

Comment: – thanks for your answer, however I’m still not sure why this is not working in rails. When I add ```Bar.new(some: :params)``` it works, so   instantinating object _should_ work also, right?

Comment: @user1105595 That’s interesting. It’s to do with Rails autoloading of classes. When you do `Bar.new` it triggers the normal autoloading process, but deserializing from Yaml doesn’t. It you run your app in production (or just with `cache_classes = true`) it should work since all classes will be already loaded (you probably don’t want to do that all the time though). I’m not sure what the best solution is, you may need to just explicitly require the files in an initializer or something.

Comment: I found this bug report that’s referring to the same issue (it’s talking about Marshal, but the `rb_path_to_class` method is the same one that’s causing the error in Psych) http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3511.

Comment: Issue can be resolved by requiring the classes in console `require 'my_class'` that was in the error.

Answer (score 2):

[Matt's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750743/2945616) provides necessary details.

But when I do changes in code and then do some task, that de-serializes some data, without page load (in AJAX) then it fails with same error.

It's better to use [require_dependency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency) than `require` to autoload your changes.

In case of module (not tested with `class`) and de-serializing using YAML, you can also instantiate your Module before de-serializing with `require` to fix the issue. [See here.](https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq/blob/bda98099e7decdf2d7287435549e84877c724b22/config/initializers/yaml_autoloader.rb#L6)

Source: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774601/2945616) and [Psych issue report in Github](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/252)

P.S: This problem persists only in Development as `config.cache_classes` is enable in Production.

Answer (score 2):

Amending to [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750743/3849157). In lieu of a pure-hash based solution (which the Psych team seems to have no interest in doing), modify the header string to strip off the object classification. I did this simply with the following code.

```
yamltext = File.read("somefile","r")
yamltext.sub!(/^--- \!.*$/,'---')
hash = YAML.load(yamltext)
```

This might fail (I don't know) if the input stream consists of several documents with different object classifiers (I dont know if that's even valid).