# Using `require 'classname'` causes "No such file to load -- Classname" error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

TLDR: Using `require 'classname'` in another model file (so I can deserialize a column) works locally but results in the `No such file to load -- Classname` error when deploying to Heroku.

---

I've made the admittedly poor design decision to serialize a model attribute which contains an array of another model's objects (`UserCategoryQueue` has a serialized queue of `Card` objects).  In order to actually de-serialize these objects, I've followed the advice in [YAML::load raises undefined class/module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750342/yamlload-raises-undefined-class-module-error) to use `require 'Card'` in the files where I need to deserialize that column.  That avoids the issue where YAML doesn't know what it's looking at when it gets to the `Card` object.

This works fine on the localhost server but has resulted in a lot of issues when deploying to Heroku, all of the form `No such file to load -- Card"`.  Initially, this occurred during the asset precompilation phase, then I precompiled the assets myself and the same error has moved to when I try to run `$ heroku run rake db:migrate` to get everything set up for the first time.

Sample Files:

```
# app/models/user_category_queue.rb
class UserCategoryQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  # Our queue of Cards
  serialize :queue, Array
end

# app/models/quiz.rb
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  require 'Card'
  ...
  # grab a random card from the user's queues
  # produces YAML error without the above require statement
  def sample_card
    self.user.user_category_queues.sample.queue.sample
  end
end
```

This ultimately resulted in the following errors on pushing to Heroku (prior to any asset precompilation attempts on my part):

> ```
>  Running: rake assets:precompile
>    rake aborted!
>    No such file to load -- Card
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/app/models/quiz.rb:18:in `<class:Quiz>'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/app/models/quiz.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
>    /tmp/build_d0e6e2b8-a3fd-4a90-ae44-e703b0093401/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
>    Tasks: TOP => environment
>    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
> ```
>
> !
>    !     Precompiling assets failed.

As I said, even when precompiling assets, though the push went fine, the ensuing database migration had the same error pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs a case-sensitive filesystem, whereas your OS may not be case-sensitive. Try changing that require to this instead:

```
 require 'card'
```

---

As a general rule of thumb, most files within Ruby are required using lowercase letters with underscores serving as a word separator, like this:

```
 require 'card_shuffler'
```